# What does sync gateway reset option does in the replicator.start(reset:true)

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

In the replicator we have a option to reset the checkpoints, by setting reset:true, what is the functionality of it, does it actually restart the whole replication operation, deleting the previously synced data or it resumes from the last successful replication and syncs the missing data.

Set the reset:true option, excepting to restart by deleting all previously synced data and syncing all from the scratch, but was actually syncing from the point where it left.

Answer (score 2):

When the checkpoint is reset, the couchbase lite doesn't send the latest checkpoint it has, to the sync gateway, hence it is expected to sync everything allocated to the device.

However, if the documents which were part of the channel subscribed earlier are not part of the channel now, they won't sync.